# How to use SELECT DISTINCT and SELECT TOP n in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I have this query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
    @Q Nvarchar(512)
AS BEGIN

SET @Q = REPLACE(@Q, N'%', N'');
SET @Q = N'"' + @Q + N'*' + N'"';

SELECT TOP 8 
       [KeywordId] as ID,
       [Keyword] as lable,
       [Keyword] as value
  FROM [dbo].[News_Keywords]
  WHERE CONTAINS ([Keyword], @Q)
  ORDER BY SortOrder, len([Keyword])

END
```

What I'm asking for, is how can I apply `DISTINCT` functionality (on column `[Keyword]`) to this statement? It's completely confusing me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and a desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` instead of `distinct`.  However, you have to decide where to put `SortOrder`.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT TOP 8 [KeywordId] as ID, [Keyword] as label, [Keyword] as value
FROM [dbo].[News_Keywords]
WHERE CONTAINS ([Keyword], @Q)
GROUP BY KeywordId, KeyWord, SortOrder
ORDER BY SortOrder, len([Keyword]);
```

Here is another:

```
SELECT TOP 8 [KeywordId] as ID, [Keyword] as label, [Keyword] as value
FROM [dbo].[News_Keywords]
WHERE CONTAINS ([Keyword], @Q)
GROUP BY KeywordId, KeyWord
ORDER BY MAX(SortOrder), len([Keyword]);
```